# Starting remote Windows services with ServiceController and impersonation

Tags: .net, windows-services, impersonation, servicecontroller

I have a .NET MVC3 application that needs to be able to turn a remote service on and off. In order to do this I am impersonating a specific user account via WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(). To test the user's permissions I can log in as the user and execute `sc.exe \\[server] start [service]` from the command prompt. I also know that the impersonate command is working as expected because the application runs anonymously and therefore cannot control services on my local machine (`.`) without impersonation, but *can* control local services with impersonation. However, when I put it together and attempt to start the remote service rather than local service I always get the error "Cannot open `[service]` service on computer '`[server]`'"

Has anyone ever experienced a similar issue? I was expecting it to be a server configuration rather than .NET issue until I realized that sc.exe works without issue. Here is an abbreviated version of the class that I am using:

```
public class Service
{
    public string Name;
    public bool Running;
    private ServiceController serviceController;

    public Service(string name, string host)
    {
        Name = name;

        serviceController = new ServiceController(Name, host);
        Running = serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;
    }

    public bool StartService()
    {
        ServiceControllerPermission scp = new ServiceControllerPermission(ServiceControllerPermissionAccess.Control, serviceController.MachineName, Name);
        scp.Assert();

        serviceController.Start();
        serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        serviceController.Refresh();

        Running = serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;

        return Running;
    }
}
```

One additional note: If instead of the server I point the application at another Windows 7 PC on the domain and change the impersonation credentials to those of the owner of that PC, I am actually able to remotely control their services without issue.

Per request, I am adding the impersonation code here. It is a little longer so bear with me:

```
public class Impersonate
{
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
        String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    public bool impersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                {
                    tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                    impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    if (impersonationContext != null)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(token);
                        CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token);
        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
        return false;
    }

    public void undoImpersonation()
    {
        impersonationContext.Undo();
    }
}
```

I call this code just before attempting to start or stop the service:

```
Service s = new Service(ServiceName, MachineName);

if (Impersonation.impersonateValidUser(Username, Domain, Password))
{
    if (s.Running)
        s.StopService();
    else
        s.StartService();

    Impersonation.undoImpersonation();
}
```

It may be worth noting that I can list the services and get the status of an individual service (as I do here) just fine - it is only when I go to start or stop the service that I run into trouble.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are performing the impersonation? I suspect that could be where the issue is.

Comment: @competent_tech Thanks for your help. I have added the impersonation-related code into the question.

Comment: Are you using an AD domain for the domain or the local computer running the service?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I've found the answer:

In the impersonation method **LogonUserA**

use **LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE** (= 5) instead of **LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE**.

Make sure that the user that you're impersonating is the same user that runs the service.

In my case, the user is included in Local Policies --> Start session as service. I have not tested with an user not included in that local policy.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, that was correct if teh user you want to impersonate is a machine administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was correct if the user you want to impersonate is a machine administrator. If it is not, then you have to give the user the particular rights to start the service.

As I am not a network admin, I didn't know how to make it, but I have found this link that explains how to do it with the subinacl tool:

- [**http://www.waynezim.com/2010/02/how-to-set-permission-on-a-service-using-subinacl/**](http://www.waynezim.com/2010/02/how-to-set-permission-on-a-service-using-subinacl/)

To download

- [**http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510)

And finally, the command line would be:

- **subinacl /service SERVICENAME /grant=DOMAINNAME\USERNAME Users=TO**

Users=TO grants start/stop permissions to the user

In this case you have to impersonate the user with the **INTERACTIVE** mode and not with the **SERVICE** mode